# Firestore - "Failed to get document because the client is offline" - only occurring for Cypress

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore, cypress

I am getting the following error when testing my Ionic Angular app with Firebase when I try to log in.

> "Failed to get document because the client is offline"

The app is hosted on http://localhost:8100/ and works fine with the same login details used manually.
The Cypress testing was working fine last time I did it about a month ago.
I have not changed any code/packages in the app since then.

**Any suggestions on what this could be?**
Could it be

1. Related to my internet connection
2. Something about the app or Cypress
3. Something changed on the Firebase backend
4. Other

My Ionic Angular app is using Firebase 8.2.5 with Angularfire 6.1.5 and Cypress 12.9.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was 2 the cypress test code.
I had to remove the following:

```
cy.intercept({ resourceType: /xhr|fetch/ }, { log: false })
```

And add the following:

```
cy.wrap(Cypress.automation('remote:debugger:protocol', {
      command: 'Network.clearBrowserCache',
    }))
    indexedDB.deleteDatabase('firebaseLocalStorageDb');
```

to the beforeEach(() =>